# Dynamically pass link to facebook share button

Tags: facebook, button

I literally searched the internet from top to bottom but I can't find the answer.
Is it possible to dynamically pass links to facebook share button or dynamically create multiple share buttons, each on click? I was trying to achieve it with js, but I could only generate one button at time and couldn't change the link on it. Any suggestions, links to articles?

Comment: Of course it is possible to dynamically pass the URL to share to the button. The documentation clearly explains what parameter you need to use for that.

Comment: If you want to modify an already existing button, or get new buttons you added after the SDK has already initialized, parsed - then you would need to call `FB.XFBML.parse` after you updated the respective attributes, resp. inserted the new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Share Dialog to share dynamic links with JavaScript and the Facebook JavaScript SDK:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/